# Polynomial irreducibility over $\mathbb{F} _{7^n}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I recently came across [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573666/proving-that-f-x32-is-irreducible-in-mathbff-49x-and-is-f-irre) from a while ago.

In it, an affirmation is made: The smallest extension of $\mathbb{F}_7$ in which an irreducible cubic polynomial has a root is $\mathbb{F}_{7^3}$. Therefore, since the polynomial $X^3+2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_7$ (easy to check), it is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_{7^2}$ and reducible in $\mathbb{F}_{7^3}$.

On the other hand, I have made a program that checks all the possible roots for that polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_{7^3}=\mathbb{F}_{343}$, and it has not found any roots.

Since I do not understand the argument, can anyone give me a hand? Is the reasoning in the question linked wrong?

Comment: This polynomial most certainly has all its three roots in $\Bbb{F}_{7^3}$. My first suspicion is that something is wrong in your construction of the field $\Bbb{F}_{7^3}$. I might construct it as
$$\Bbb{F}_{7^3}=\Bbb{F}_7(\root3\of2)=\{a+b\root3\of2+c\root3\of4\mid a,b,c\in\Bbb{F}_7\},$$ when the choices $a=c=0, b=-1$ give a root $-\root3\of2$. The other roots are gotten with $a=c=0$, $b=-2$ and $a=c=0$, $b=-4=3$. After all $2$ is primitive third root of unity in this field, so multiplying any root by $2$ gives another.

Comment: Technically, it is preferrable to denote the coset of $x$ in $\Bbb{F}_7[x]/(x^3-2)$ by $\alpha$ rather than $\root3\of2$, lest it gets confused with the real number $\root3\of2$, but I'm too used to such abuse of notation :-)

Comment: So, what does your program do exactly?

Comment: How do you represent $\mathbb{F}_{7^3}$ in the computer to do the calculations? A common error is to tuse the integers modulo $7^3$, which is not the correct structure.

Comment: Yes, I definitely messed that up and got confused between $\mathbb{F_{7^3}}$ and $\mathbb{Z_{7^3}}$.

Comment: I thought as much. Note that $\mathbb{Z}_{7^3}$ is not a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X^3 + 2$ *does* have a root in $\mathbb F_{7^3}$. There are a few ways to see this. For example:

- $\mathbb F_{7^3}$ is the splitting field for the polynomial $X^{7^3} - X$ over $\mathbb F_7$. (Indeed, many books *construct* $\mathbb F_{7^3}$ this way.) Now suppose that $L$ is an extension of $\mathbb F_{7^3}$ containing an element $\theta$ that is a root of $X^3 + 2$ (e.g. $L$ could be the splitting field of $X^3 + 2$ over $\mathbb F_{7^3}$). Since $\theta^3 + 2 = 0$, it follows that $\theta^{7^3} = \theta \times (\theta^3)^{114} = \theta \times (-2)^{114} = \theta \times ((-2)^6)^{19} = \theta \times 1^{19} = \theta$. Thus $\theta$ is a root of $X^{7^3} - X$. Since $X^{7^3} - X$ splits completely in $\mathbb F_{7^3}$, it must be the case that $\theta \in \mathbb F_{7^3}$.
- Alternatively, we could consider the field $E = \mathbb F_7 [x] / (x^3 + 2)$. (We know $E$ is a field because $X^3 + 2$ is irreducible in $F_7 [x]$.) Now $E$ contains a root of $X^3 + 2$; indeed, the element $\theta := x \in E$ is a root of $X^3 + 2$. Since $E = \mathbb F_7(\theta)$ and the minimal polynomial of $\theta$ over $\mathbb F_7$ is the cubic polynomial $X^3 + 2$, it follows that $[E : \mathbb F_7] = 3$, i.e. $E$ contains $7^3$ elements. But $\mathbb F_{7^3}$ is the *unique* field with $7^3$ elements! So $E$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb F_{7^3}$. If $f : E \to \mathbb F_{7^3}$ is this isomorphism, then the fact that $\theta^3 + 2 = 0$ in $E$ implies that $f(\theta)^3 + 2 = 0$ in $\mathbb F_{7^3}$. Thus $f(\theta)$ is a root of $X^3 + 2$ in $\mathbb F_{7^3}$. (Furthermore, $\mathbb F_{7^3}$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb F_{7^3}$, so we can also infer that $X^3 + 2$ splits *completely* in $\mathbb F_{7^3}$.)

Anyway, both of these arguments show that $X^3 + 2$ has a root in $\mathbb F_{7^3}$.

How did you write computer program to do arithmetic in $\mathbb F_{7^3}$? It's hard to see how you could have figured out how arithmetic works in $\mathbb F_{7^3}$ without arguing along the lines of what I've written out. [Also, remember that $\mathbb F_{7^3}$ is not the same thing as $\mathbb Z_{7^3}$  - this is a common source of confusion!]

Comment: Great! thanks for the answer, the argument is much more clear now. Indeed, I got confused between $\mathbb{F_{7^3}}$ and $\mathbb{Z_{7^3}}$, but I now understand the difference. One little remark, in the first argument it should say $((-2)^6)^{19 }$ instead of $(-2^6)^{19 }$(5th line).

Comment: Glad it helped, and well spotted

Comment: One question, why is $(-2)^{16}=1$? What congruence are you taking and why?

Comment: $-2$ is an element of $\mathbb F_{7} \subset \mathbb F_{7^3}$, and certainly $(-2)^6 = 1$ in $\mathbb F_7$.

Comment: Think of this subfield $\mathbb F_7$ inside $\mathbb F_{7^3}$ as being the elements $\{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 \} $.

Comment: Oh, okay! At first I though you were doing congruences mod 3 (degree of polynomial) and I was getting confused. Two questions: $(-2)^6=1$ in $\mathbb{F}_7$ simply because $64\equiv 1$ mod 7, right? And also, I thought because you are in an extension (which is not $\mathbb{Z}_{7^3}$, of course) you couldn’t use the same arithmetic that in the prime field, can you?

Comment: What I mean is, arithmetic in $\mathbb{F}_{7^3}$ doesn’t work like in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, right? Then, why can you use the same rules as if you were in $\mathbb{Z}_7$? Can you do it only for those elements that belong to $\mathbb{F}_7$?

Comment: You're right that arithmetic in $F_{7^3}$ doesn't work like arithmetic in $Z_7$. However, $F_{7^3}$ contains a subfield that is isomorphic to $Z_7$. The element $-2$ is contained in this subfield. Therefore, you can do arithmetic on the element $-2$ using the laws of arithmetic valid in $Z_7$

Comment: To spell this out: since $-2$ is inside the subfield that is isomorphic to $Z_7$, the element $(-2)^6$ is also inside this subfield, and is equal to $64$ (which is also in this subfield), which is equal to $1$ using the laws of arithmetic that apply to the subfield $Z_7$

Comment: So in short, the answer to both your questions is "Yes, you're correct"

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple argument. We need to show that $\mathbb{F}_{343}$ contains a cube root of $a=-2$. The element $a$ has order $6$ in the multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}_{343}^{\times}$, which is cyclic of order $343-1=342$. Now since $\mathbb{F}_{343}^{\times}$ is cyclic, and the quotient $342/6 = 57$ is divisible by three, we can divide any element of $\mathbb{F}_{343}^{\times}$ of order $6$ by $3$.

Indeed, the elements of $\mathbb{F}_7^{\times}$ within $\mathbb{F}_{343}^{\times}$ are exactly the elements of the form $\alpha^{57}$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{343}^{\times}$. Hence there exists an $\alpha$ with $\alpha^{57}=a$, and then $\beta=\alpha^{19}$ satisfies $\beta^3=a$. Since $2^3=1$ in $\mathbb{F}_7$, the other two cube roots of $a$ are given by $2\beta$ and $4\beta$.